# How do I interpret the expiry returned by AcquireCredentialsHandle (Kerberos)?

Tags: winapi, kerberos, sspi

The Windows SSPI call `AcquireCredentialsHandle` returns a time stamp indicating when the credentials handle will expire. The docs seem to be saying that the `TimeStamp` structure should have the same format as a `FILETIME` structure. However, when I use this function with the "Kerberos" package, the result makes no sense when treated as a `FILETIME`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SECURITY_WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#include <security.h>

int main() {

  TimeStamp expiry;
  int aquireCode;
  CredHandle credHandle;
  BOOL timeOk;
  SYSTEMTIME sysTime;

  aquireCode = AcquireCredentialsHandle(
          NULL,
          "Kerberos",
          SECPKG_CRED_OUTBOUND,
          NULL,
          NULL,
          NULL,
          NULL,
          &credHandle,
          &expiry);

  printf("result = %d\n", aquireCode);
  printf("upper = %d (%X)\n", expiry.HighPart, expiry.HighPart);
  printf("lower = %d (%X)\n", expiry.LowPart, expiry.LowPart);

  timeOk = FileTimeToSystemTime((FILETIME*)&expiry, &sysTime);
  printf("time covert ok = %d\n", timeOk);
  printf("%4d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d\n", sysTime.wYear, sysTime.wMonth, sysTime.wDay, sysTime.wHour, sysTime.wMinute, sysTime.wSecond);
}
```

On my system, this prints:

```
result = 0
upper = 2147483530 (7FFFFF8A)
lower = -1488801793 (A742AFFF)
time covert ok = 1
30828/09/13 12:48:05
```

If it's not a `FILETIME`, what is it?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm seeing exactly the same thing and the web seems silent on the matter.

Comment: No, I never got to the bottom of it. Luckily I didn't end up needing to know the expiry for the problem I was solving.

Comment: Attention, your code contains a bug. ACH returns a time object in local time but FileTimeToSystemTime requires a UTC time object to convert. Use LocalTimeToFileTime in the first place.

Btw, I have the same stupid date. Must be some MS idioticy. Digest or NTLM deliver completely different dates. I would say that this expiry is absolutely useless.